# Polymer init halt on "Running generator" (polymer-cli 1.8.0, Polymer 3.0)

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, polymer-cli

I'm facing the an issue, the `polymer init` halted on

`Running generator polymer-init-polymer-3-element:app...`

same on win7 and MINGW64_NT-6.1, with polymer --version = 1.8.0, nodejs --version = v10.3.0

Answer (score 0):

it seems an issue causing by `yield prompt`

here's my temporary solution - edit the source code of polymer-cli to make my choices:

1. find **polymer-cli/lib/init/init.js**

update

`const generatorName = yield util_1.prompt(createSelectPrompt(env));`

with your selection

`createSelectPrompt(env);
const generatorName = 'polymer-init-polymer-3-element:app';`

2. find **polymer-cli/element/element.js**

update

`this.props = (yield this.prompt(prompts));`

with

`this.props = {name: 'my-element', 'description': 'MyElement Demo for Polymer 3.0'};`